# Excel formula that returns a specific value based on if the date is before, during, or after a given date?

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I am trying to write an excel formula that returns a specific value based on if a given [month & year] falls before, between, and after a date range.

[image: Screenshot]

In the above screenshot, I have the date range: `Column M - Column O`.
In subsequent columns (`Column P - Column AC`, etc.) is a given `month & year`.

- If `Column P - Column AC` dates are **less than** `Column M` it needs
  to return **`Not Started`**.
- If `Column P - Column AC` dates fall **between** the dates in `Column
  M - Column O`, it needs to return **`In Progress`**.
- If `Column P - Column AC` dates fall **after or equal to** the dates
  in `Column O`, it needs to return **`Complete`** for all the following
  months.

What I am trying to do with this data is eventually make a historical trend chart that shows a count of each status by `month & year`, but I need to assign these statuses to each month first before I can do this. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: What formulas have you attempted so far? A nested `IF` statement should work for your problem.

Comment: So what happen if `column O` is blank?  Complete or In Progress?

Comment: It should be In Progress

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula `=IF(C$1-$A2<0,"Not Started",IF(C$1-$B2<0,"In Progress","Completed"))` in cell `C2`. Drag it across whole table. Make sure your dates are really dates and not text values.

[image]

Comment: For some reason, this does not work. Maybe because the Readiness column and Last Sched Mig column are part of a sharepoint table? I made sure that the format was dates and not text... but I am still stuck

Comment: when you format change all dates to general, do they all change to numbers, like 42705?

Comment: @G.Pa, are you using US version of Excel?  if not, maybe you will need to change `,` to `;`.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a revised version of @KresimirL's answer:

```
=IF(C$1-$A2<0,"Not Started",IF(OR(C$1-$B2<0,$B2=""),"In Progress","Completed"))
```

This should work for you.

[image]

Comment: For some reason, cell H2 shows as Not Started, even though it should say In Progress. Logically thinking if Apr-17 minus Apr-17 is 0 then it should be In Progress because that's when it starts. Any ideas why?

Comment: I do have `In Progress` in the screenshot.  Guess what you have is due to the cells `A2 and H1` that you may have different setup.  Go to `Formulas > Formula Auditing > Evaluate Formula` and step through to see what you have on your data.